# efficiency of using 'class' in Fortran 2003?

Tags: oop, class, fortran, performance

Fortran 2003 supports data polymorphism by using class, like:

```
subroutine excute(A)
  class(*) :: A

  select type (A)
    class is ()
      ...
    type is () 
      ...
  end select

end subroutine
```

My question is: if I need to call this subroutine a huge amount of times, whether it will slow the code down because of the SELECT statement?

Comment: Are you querying the efficiency of "class" in a select type construct, or the efficiency of select type constructs in general (in which case the question title might need an edit)?  When you say "slow the code down"... relative to what?

Comment: I mean the efficiency of select type constructs. Sorry for the confusion. I used a title like that because I think the 'class' statement always goes with a 'select type' statement to take advantage of the idea of "class of objects". Is that correct?

Comment: Not necessarily, if you have e.g. a `type, extends(super) :: sub`, then a `class(super)` variable can always access the components of its "declared type" `super`. Your example is an _unlimited_ polymorphic, which is special in that it has no declared type, so then indeed you need `select type` to determine its dynamic type before you can reference it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SELECT TYPE is typically implemented by the descriptor for the polymorphic object (`CLASS(*) :: A` here) having a token or pointer or index of similar that designates the dynamic type of the object.  Execution of the select type is then like a SELECT CASE on this token, with the additional complication that non-polymorphic type guards (TYPE IS) are matched in preference to polymorphic guards (CLASS IS).

There is some overhead associated with this construct.  That overhead is more than if the code did nothing at all.  Then again, code that does nothing at all is rarely useful.  So the real question is whether the use of SELECT TYPE is better or worse execution speed wise to some alternative approach that provides the necessary level of functionality (which might be less than the full functionality that SELECT TYPE provides) that your code needs.  To answer that, you would need to define and implement that approach, and then measure the difference in speed in a context that's relevant to your use case.

As indicated in the comments, an unlimited polymorphic entity is essentially a type safe way of storing something of any type.  In this case, SELECT TYPE is required at some stage to be able to access the value of the stored thing.  However, this is only a rather specific subset of F2003's support for polymorphism.  In more typical examples SELECT TYPE would not be used at all - the behaviour associated with the dynamic type of an object would be accessed by calling overridden bindings of the declared type.

Comment: +1 for also explaining that while some efficiency is usually sacrificed for obtaining shorter/clearer/more versatile code, this is not necessarily bad. The `class(*)` is like a C(++) `void*`, but more limited without the ability to type cast. Since they are rather cumbersome, I have not found satisfactory use for them so far, though I do use regular polymorphic variables often.

Comment: @sigma I don't think I explained an efficiency/clarity tradeoff (an efficiency/capability trade-off is implicitly suggested, but that's different), besides which I don't necessarily agree with the "usually" part your statement.  In terms of a comparison with `void *`, "limited" only arises because they are covering somewhat different concepts and capability.  `void*` doesn't "remember" the dynamic type of the object.  `TYPE(C_PTR)` is its equivalent (by design/specification).  `CLASS(*)` is more "like" boost::any.